# Ubuntu 20.04 sudo apt update Error while installing Neo4j=3.5.5

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, ubuntu-20.04

sudo apt update
Error Messages:
1:E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://debian.neo4j.com/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/neo4j.gpg !=
2: E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: What steps did you take to get to that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same problem. so I just removed the files causing this. by these commands

```
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/neo4j.gpg
```

and

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neo4j.list
```

I think, may be this will remove the necessary files for neo4j installation also. So, may be you'd have to re-install neo4j if you want it again. However, this get rid of that error mentioned in this post, and `sudo apt update` is running now.